# media player wont play drag and dropped media files

Tags: mount, files, devices, transfer

I just got a Sony nwz-e384 walkman. I transfer files Drag and drop, but the device refuses to play them. When I do the same files, in the same way (drag and drop) on windows, the device will play them. I have not installed any additional software in windows, as far as I know its being treated as a mounted storage device.

The device seems to mount fine, and if I plug it back into my Linux computer, I can see the files.

Here is the relevant info from dmesg:

```
[ 4958.054058] usb 3-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 4958.146981] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0882
[ 4958.146984] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 4958.146985] usb 3-1.3: Product: WALKMAN
[ 4958.146986] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer: SONY
[ 4958.146987] usb 3-1.3: SerialNumber: 104317E4392882
[ 4958.147498] usb-storage 3-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4958.147870] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1.3:1.0
[ 4959.146588] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SONY     WALKMAN          1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 4959.150394] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4959.151707] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3766528 2048-byte logical blocks: (7.53 GB/7.18 GiB)
[ 4959.153079] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4959.153082] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 3e 00 00 00
[ 4959.153825] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 4959.153827] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4959.154955] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3766528 2048-byte logical blocks: (7.53 GB/7.18 GiB)
[ 4959.157457]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4959.158578] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3766528 2048-byte logical blocks: (7.53 GB/7.18 GiB)
[ 4959.160330] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Here is the relevant info from fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7713849344 bytes, 3766528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 2048 = 2048 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048 bytes / 2048 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 2048 bytes / 2048 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           5 3766527 3766523  7.2G  b W95 FAT32
```

Here and is the Relevant info from the mount:

```
mount | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1 on /media/j0h/WALKMAN type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Is there anything I’m missing here? are there errors I am not seeing? What might I try to get this to work using Linux?

As a side note, I had an older version of the same device, and that one worked fine in Linux.